# length of the longest substring of given string so that rearrangement of its characters form PALINDROME

Tags: python

- Only lower case string as input.
- Only words as input
- Invalid if characters like "@","#"... are present
- Find the length of the longest substring of given string so that the characters in it can be rearranged to form a palindrome.
- Output the length

I am unable to put it in terms of programming in python.

please help.

My line of thinking was to keep an initial counter as 1(as even a word with completely different letters will have 1 by default)

then add 2 for every 1 match in letters

Sample input: "letter"

Sample output: 5 #(1(by default + 2(for 2"t"s) + 2(for 2"e"s))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to figure out the length of the longest substring which can be rearranged to form a palindrome:

```
def longestSubstring(s: str):
 
    # To keep track of the last
    # index of each xor
    n = len(s)
    index = dict()
 
    # Initialize answer with 0
    answer = 0
 
    mask = 0
    index[mask] = -1
 
    # Now iterate through each character
    # of the string
    for i in range(n):
 
        # Convert the character from
        # [a, z] to [0, 25]
        temp = ord(s[i]) - 97
 
        # Turn the temp-th bit on if
        # character occurs odd number
        # of times and turn off the temp-th
        # bit off if the character occurs
        # even number of times
        mask ^= (1 << temp)
 
        # If a mask is present in the index
        # Therefore a palindrome is
        # found from index[mask] to i
        if mask in index.keys():
            answer = max(answer,
                         i - index[mask])
 
        # If x is not found then add its
        # position in the index dict.
        else:
            index[mask] = i
 
        # Check for the palindrome of
        # odd length
        for j in range(26):
 
            # We cancel the occurrence
            # of a character if it occurs
            # odd number times
            mask2 = mask ^ (1 << j)
            if mask2 in index.keys():
 
                answer = max(answer,
                             i - index[mask2])
 
    return answer
```

This algorithm is basically O(N*26). XOR basically checks if the amount of a certain character is even or odd. For every character in your string there is a certain XOR sequence of every character up to that point which tells you which characters have appeared an odd number of time and which characters have appeared an even number of times. If the same sequence has already been encountered in the past then you know that you have found a palindrome, because you have become back to where you started in the XOR sequence aka there are an even number of every character which appears between this point and the start point. If there is an even number of every character which appear between two points in the string, then you can form a palindrome out of them. The odd length check is just a special case to check for palindromes which are of odd length. It works by just pretending sequentially if a character appears an odd number of times, that it just assumes it to occur an even number of times to handle the special case of the character in the middle of an odd length palindrome.

Edit: [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-substring-whose-characters-can-be-rearranged-to-form-a-palindrome/) is the link to the original code and explanation.